# Code first "enable-migration" scaffolding doesn't capture datetime indexes from SQL DB

Tags: entity-framework

On my new project I decided to try out the code first database method.  It took a while to figure out how to get things working but now I've captured the model and can create migrations.

I just noticed something odd this morning when working with adding in a new DateTime column. I needed to add an index to this column and went in and looked at what was scaffolded from the enable-migration to copy/paste the index configuration. I didn't see a any of my other DateTime columns that had an index assigned to them in there.

I verified the DB and the indexes are there on the DateTime columns.  So I dropped the DB, deleted the migrations folder and did the "enable-migrations" again with the same result.

I would just go in and add the index manually in the DB context file but I'm not feeling good about the scaffolding not pulling it in like it wasn't supported.

Am I doing something wrong on the enable-migrations that is not capturing the indexes on the DateTime columns or do I just need to add those manually in the db context file?  (Is it supported?)

Comment: I don't understand.  In Code-First, you have to have the index configured in the DbContext for the the `enable-migration` command to generate it.

Comment: I'm capturing an existing DB that was started by doing database first.  That generates the initial model.  I ran these steps: https://devgush.com/2014/02/24/migrating-a-project-from-database-first-to-code-first/

Comment: So you're saying that `scaffold-dbcontext` doesn't generate your indexex configuration on the generated DbContext?

Comment: It did but not on any of the columns that are of type "DateTime"